# Reuse instance of once created controller in asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The task is very special. As we know asp.net mvc creating new instance of controller for every request. The target is to write a class inherit Controller contains some data and created once and then used for every requests. For example:
We have a class:

```
public class UserWorkspaceController : Controller
{
    public SomeDataClass UserData;
    public List<string> AnotherData;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    /// another methods here
}
```

Another thing. We have something like this:

```
public static class UserWorspacesStorage
{
    public static Dictionary<string,  UserWorkspaceController> storage = new Dictionary<string,  UserWorkspaceController>(); 

public static UserWorkspaceController GetUserWorkspace(string someCookeString)
    {
        UserWorkspaceController requested;
        if (!storage.TryGetValue(someCookeString, out requested))
        {
            requested = new UserWorkspaceController();
            storage.Add(requested);
        }
        return requested;
    }
}
```

So. As you understand,  we need to use some cookie string (key) then ask static class for controller for this key. If it was not found in dictionnary it will be created and placed in dictionary. At the next request exist controller will be extracted from dictionary.

You may ask WHY? :)
Becouse the target is to "migrate" exist WinForms application to Web (asp.net mvc). So if my idea is possible it will be easy to solve the  task!
Thanks.

Comment: "mvc creating new instance of controller for every request." - is not true, it asks factory to provide one (and the factory usually creates new controller, but does not have to)... But despite this you will likely be better off redesigning your code to be more web-friendly rather than trying to hack winForms code into web... Also try not to re-invent `Session` per-user storage with your static dictionary...

Comment: Easy does not always mean better.  One hack will eventually lead to another, creating slow, bloated, poor performing apps.  The web is not the desktop world and to treat it as such usually ends up coming back to haunt you.

Comment: I tried doing something like your static dictionary but it only lives as long as the AppDomain so it's not really static forever.

Comment: Is there any update on this? @user2598575, are you aware of MVC is a stateless concept? If so, breaking this will challenge you on many other fronts.

Comment: Reusing of exist controller is impossible by MVC concept. I have solve it by implementing custom controller factory can load and save state of my controllers then creating/destroing them. Its so easy to implement. For example create an interface (`StatedController`) with two methods `LoadState` and `SaveState`, then inherint from default `Controller` and implement this interface. So use custom `ControllerFactory` and call `SaveState` and `LoadState` in controller if its implement `StatedController` thats it :)